# Google omniauth-openid login not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, omniauth, google-openid

For the past 2 years I had no issues with users logging in with Google using the omniauth-openid gem. All of a sudden logins have stopped working and I get a vague error:

```
WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud using stateless mode.
(google) Callback phase initiated.
(google) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials encountered.
```

Any ideas whats going on here? I've searched everywhere with no answers.

Comment: It could be that google has changed it's API and the omniauth gem is not up to date.

Comment: where can I find out if Google updated their API?

Comment: I might try the google open-id google groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the old omniauth-openid gem and fixed this issue by updating to the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem.